# powershell rename files in subfolders based on csv

Tags: powershell, csv

As suggested by this forum link that is similar to my case,
I followed below link and it actually worked perfectly (I did tweak it a bit to meet my needs):

[Can I rename files in subfolders based on.CSV file using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55433812/can-i-rename-files-in-subfolders-based-on-csv-file-using-powershell/56745492#56745492)

but I have another question related to it.
In the csv I have, it is mentioned folder/name.ext, where from the link, what it does was actually search through folders and rename all files but it doesn't rename the folders listed in csv.
What parameter do I need to add to include folders as well?

```
Oname,NName
folder1/Name1,NewName1
folder1/Name2,Newname2
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path "YOUR_FILE_NAME.csv" # READING CSV FILE

foreach ($item in $data) # FOR EACH LOOP IN ALL CSV ENTRIES
{
    Rename-Item -Path "${$item.Oname}" -NewName "${$item.NName}"
} # END OF FOR EACH LOOP
```

Comment: now it's showing these error,
Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At line:5 char:23
+     Rename-Item -Path "${$item.Oldname}" -NewName "${$item.NewName}"
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: which are  your csv headers ?

Comment: sorry, i did renamed the oname to oldname, according to my csv header

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to rename the folders as well but in the example csv you gave, you haven't included what you want the old folders to be renamed to.

I don't know how you created your list of folder/files but if you could re-create your csv to look like this:

```
Oldname,NewName
Name1,NewName1
Name2,Newname2
Folder1,Newfolder1
Folder1,Newfolder2
```

then the code provided by Niraj Gajjar would rename all files and folders in your list:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path "YOUR_FILE_NAME.csv" # READING CSV FILE

foreach ($item in $data) # FOR EACH LOOP IN ALL CSV ENTRIES
{
    Rename-Item -Path "${$item.Oldname}" -NewName "${$item.NewName}"
} # END OF FOR EACH LOOP
```

If for some reason you need to keep the format of the csv as "folder1/Name,Newname1", there are different solutions.